# stuck with simple php equation

Tags: php

I have a list of games and hours played being grabbed from an XML into a `foreach`. They format the time as 1.8 hours rather than 1 hour 48 minutes.

Everything in the code below is working except for the last `elseif`. It is supposed to grab the games that are more than 6 minutes played but less than 60, convert it, and then add "minutes" at the end.

Right now, it's only displaying "0 minutes" for all of those games.

```
$hoursplayed = $game->hoursOnRecord;
        if ($hoursplayed < .1) {
        $zeros = $zeros + 1;
        $hoursplayed = 0;}          
        elseif ($hoursplayed >= 1){
        $nonzeros = $nonzeros + 1; 
        }
        elseif ($hoursplayed >= .1 && $hoursplayed < 1) {
        $hoursplayed = ($hoursplayed * 60) . " minutes";
        }
```

Comment: If your first two conditions are already checking for games less than 6 minutes and for an hour or over, you don't need to have a final elseif, just an else. It should run the same, but I think it makes the code easier to read.

Comment: If I try that snippet with `$hoursplayed = 0.3` and use `echo` to print, it displays "18 minutes" as expected. I think your bug is in the code that sets `$game->$hoursOnRecord`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but it runs fine!
[Working demo here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9chUCa).

Try this:

```
$hoursplayed = (float) $game->hoursOnRecord;
```

Comment: strange. it must be something else on the page. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your code is pretty messy; this is how I'd write it:

```
<?php
$hours_float = $game -> hoursOnRecord;
$hours = floor($hours_float);
$minutes = round(($hours_float - $hours) * 60);
if (($hours > 0 || $minutes > 6) && $hours < 1)
    {
    echo $hours . ' hour' . ($hours === 1 ? '' : 's') . ' ' . $minutes . ' minute' . ($minutes === 1 ? '' : 's');
    }
```